# Can't upload image using Angular's HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am able to upload an image perfectly fine using the native fetch POST:

```
let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
        console.log(event.target.files[0]);
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/file/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JWT
            },
            body:formData
        }).then(response => console.log(response));
```

However, when I try this using Angular's HttpClient, the request fails since the 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' is not added.

My Angular code:

The file where I'm calling the service:

```
this.fileSaverService.uploadImage(event.target.files[0]).subscribe(
            (data)=>{
                console.log(data);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
```

The fileSaverService:

```
  uploadImage(fileToUpload) {
    const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8080/file/upload';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload);
    return this.api
      .post(endpoint, formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} });
}
```

The this.api:

```
  post(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts: any = {}) {    
    reqOpts.headers = this.handleHeaders(reqOpts.headers);
    return this.http.post(endpoint, JSON.stringify(body), reqOpts);
  }
```

If I add the header manually when using HttpClient, I get this header without the boundary:

[image]

However the native fetch adds this header automatically with the boundary if I don't specify a header and this works perfectly:

[image: Conent type with native fetch]

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code in your question:

1. By setting `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` *yourself*, the serialisation of your `FormData` will not result in the correct header with boundaries being set behind the scenes.
2. In your `post` function, you have `JSON.stringify(body)`, which is converting your `FormData` object into a JSON string. After doing this, you're simply attempting to POST a string rather than a complete FormData object.